# Minimization of Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, minimize

I am looking for algorithms or a program that can minimize Boolean expressions w.r.t. the number of characters used in the resulting expression. I am aware of the usual minimization algorithms, like Quine-McCluskey and Espresso, but they always produce disjunctive normal forms that may be much longer than expressions involving clever bracketing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking for minimization of the logical gate count. The resulting network of logical gates could have multiple levels and different gate types (`NAND`, `NOR`, `XOR`, ...).

Synthesis of multilevel logic is a rather hard problem which has been subject of research for the last five decades. A popular system in this area is `misII`, developed 1988-1993 (sic!) at the University of California.

Try `Logic Friday 1`, a `Windows` tool which presents a nice `GUI` around `misII` and `Espresso`.